# blazor "Could not find a MSBuild project file"?

Tags: .net, blazor

i tried:
G:\GG\blazor Application>dotnet watch run

but it returns:
watch : Could not find a MSBuild project file in 'G:\GG\blazor Application'. Specify which project to use with the --project option.

Comment: Try the `G:\GG\blazor Application\blazor Application` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G:\GG\blazor Application\blazor Application worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me too.  I 'think' it's because all the files that contain the actual project are one level down..speaking from if it's created via vs.  so if OP's file structure is the same as mine, that level would have contained a folder with all of the supporting files and a .sln file.  When you run the command, it says, yeah nothing here for me to do go away.  but one level down is where it finds what it's looking for.  If you're new (like I am) it can be a bit confusing to understand the error message at first....